# Computed Buckets with cts:field-values

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there a way to pass the **computed-buckets** for `cts:field-values` ? 
I have a field range index created.. and I cannot use `search:search` as I build my `cts:query` dynamically..

I want to calculate for my `cts:query` the frequency of buckets...

this is what my buckets will look if I were to use `search:search`

```
 <range type="xs:dateTime" facet="true">
      <computed-bucket lt="P0Y" ge="-P1Y" anchor="start-of-year" name="lastyear">Last Year</computed-bucket>
      <computed-bucket lt="-P1Y" ge="-P100Y" anchor="start-of-year" name="older">Older</computed-bucket>
      <computed-bucket lt="P1M" ge="P0M" anchor="start-of-month" name="thismonth">This Month</computed-bucket>
      <computed-bucket lt="P1Y" ge="P0Y" anchor="start-of-year" name="thisyear">This Year</computed-bucket>
      <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
      <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
      <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
      <field name="upload_date"/>
    </range>
```

Comment: If you want to build the query, but still take advantage of Search API for facets, you can use `search:resolve`.

Comment: How do I add the <range> element to the search <options> tag as it is only valid for <contraint> tab ??

Comment: Sorry typed in too soon.. Got it.. thnx...

btw: can you answer it so I can mark it resolved...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use buckets with `values` and `tuples` in search options (e.g. for use with `search:values`) unfortunately, but as mentioned in the comment, you can at least generate a `cts:query` using `search:resolve`. Once you have the `cts:query` you can manually build the buckets you need, potentially using [cts:value-ranges](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-ranges).

It can sometimes also be worthwhile to create a custom facet that computes facet buckets dynamically. For example the dynamic-buckets-constraint I have put together a while ago:

https://github.com/grtjn/ml-constraints#dynamic-buckets-constraint

HTH!